# Is Recording Videos also prohibited like drawing or taking picture in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh

I knew that drawing shapes that has soul is not allowed in Islam, is this rule also includes Video recording?

Answer (score 1):

Drawing is not like video recording.

Video recording is considered as a reflection of objects (like a mirror or reflections on the surface of water). Wheras drawing is an act of recreating objects visually.

Islamic books and drawings cannot be considered as a reference. Proof of wheather it is prohibited or not is present in Quran and Sunna, one should look into these sources to find the answer and not into the traces of ancient muslims. Who said that those ancient muslims where applying islam correctly ?

Comment: reflection ob objects, like in mirrors, were used thousands of years ago, ... it is also know that Imam Riza told a narrative about where Allah is, and in that narrative he used the term "mirror", so mirrors were known, and common, but I am with you, if RIDHA (Rizalik) is not given, means if you do not allow it EXPLICITELY than anything is forbidden!